# Perl substr error

Tags: perl

I have problem with Perl substr function. It is so simple, but anyway... Don't know what is the problem.

```
sub encode_date
{
    $date = $_[0];
    $day = substr($date, 0, 2);
    $month = substr($date, 2, 2);
    $year = substr($date, 6, 4);

    return "$year-$month-$day";
}
```

Sub accept "DD.MM.YYYY" formatted string and have to convert it to "YYYY-MM-DD" format.

**Input :** 09.09.1993
**Output :** 0-09-93-19 ???

Can anybody explain what's wrong, please.

p.s.: I wrote another sub for decoding date (from 'yyyy-mm-dd' to 'dd.mm.yyyy') and all work properly.

```
sub decode_date
{
    $date = $_[0];
    $year = substr $date, 0, 4;
    $month = substr $date, 5, 2;
    $day = substr $date, 8, 2;
    return $day.".".$month.".".$year;
}
```

Sure, I tried both `substr $date, 0, 2;` and `substr($date, 0, 2);` and different combinations of the return value.

Comment: I can't reproduce the output you describe; I get `1993-.0-09` (which is still wrong, of course, but at least makes sense, given that your substring offsets are wrong).

Comment: Your first example doesn't produce the output you describe. However, the first example's sub does suffer from off-by-one: The 2nd `substr` expression should be `substr( $date, 3, 2 )`.

Comment: True. $date was encoded 2 times. That was the problem. `encode_date(encode_date($date));` something like this but in different files. Ty.

Answer (score 3):

Month starts at index `3`, not `2`.

```
sub encode_date
{
    my ($date) = @_;
    my $day = substr($date, 0, 2);
    my $month = substr($date, 3, 2);
    my $year = substr($date, 6, 4);

    return "$year-$month-$day";
}
```

Perhaps better way would be splitting string by non-digit(`.`), reverse numbers, and join them with dash `-`

```
sub encode_date
{
    my ($date) = @_;

    return join "-", reverse split /\D/, $date;
}
```

Comment: Oops. You posted same. Good job. Devil is in the details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your offsets are wrong, because they don't take into account the separators. (For example, the month starts at offset `3`, not `2`, because it comes after the two-character date plus a period.)

That said, I think the best way to write this function is:

```
sub encode_date($) {
    if ($_[0] =~ /^(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\.(\d{4})$/) {
        return "$3-$2-$1";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sub encode_date
{
    $date = $_[0];
    $day = substr($date, 0, 2);
    $month = substr($date, 3, 2);
    $year = substr($date, 6, 4);

    return "$year-$month-$day";
}
```

There were 2 problems.
 I used `encode_date(encode_date($date));` (2 times)
Another was `$month = substr($date, 2, 2);` Correct is `$month = substr($date, 3, 2);`

Comment: It would be wise to add some parameter validation, so things like calling that function two times on the same variable would fire an error